# React keep UI responsive while canvas updates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas

So I have something like an image editor with React and a Canvas, and the canvas updates every time you drag sliders and such. But dragging sliders and interacting with the UI in general is very sluggish because the canvas updates are heavy. Is there any way to update it in the background while keeping the UI responsive?

I tried using useTransition, but I'm guessing it only works with rendering components not updating a canvas, as it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make React *trigger* canvas updates / draw actions.
Use a [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) loop to *render* the canvas state, and update the canvas state from react.

So, all your interactions get stored into some values, arrays, objects, whatever you need.

On every animation frame, your rendering code looks through that data and (re-)draws your canvas contents.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think it's plausible to update it every animation frame. But this did help me find requestIdleFrame which improved the performance by a lot.